# Uniq array by key ruby

Tags: ruby

I need a loop to iterate over a hash that looks similar to below:

```
{:client=>"CLIENT1", :mwregion=>"prod", :db=>"DBAB2", :host=>"10.193.138.23", :role=>"WEB"}
{:client=>"CLIENT1 ", :mwregion=>"prod", :db=>"DBAB2", :host=>"10.192.138.24", :role=>"WEB"}
{:client=>"CLIENT1 ", :mwregion=>"prod", :db=>"DBAB2", :host=>"10.193.138.24", :role=>"WEB"}
{:client=>"CLIENT1 ", :mwregion=>"beta", :db=>"DBAB5", :host=>"10.192.140.61", :role=>"WEB"}
{:client=>"CLIENT2 ", :mwregion=>"beta", :db=>"DBAB2", :host=>"10.193.140.61", :role=>"WEB"}
{:client=>"CLIENT2 ", :mwregion=>"train", :db=>"DBAB2", :host=>"10.192.140.59", :role=>"WEB"}
{:client=>"CLIENT2 ", :mwregion=>"train", :db=>"DBAB4", :host=>"10.193.140.59", :role=>"WEB"}
{:client=>"CLIENT3 ", :mwregion=>"prod", :db=>"DBAB3", :host=>"10.192.139.61", :role=>"JVM"}
{:client=>"CLIENT3 ", :mwregion=>"prod", :db=>"DBAB1", :host=>"10.193.139.63", :role=>"JVM"}
```

And print out just the unique values for the :client key.

```
CLIENT1
CLIENT2
CLIENT3
```

I have tried the following, but it fails

```
@var.uniq do |x|
    puts x[:client]
end

main.rb:12:in `<main>': undefined method `uniq' for #<Sequel::MySQL::Dataset:0x000000011ca1a0> (NoMethodError)
```

Also, ruby version is:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Are you looping over an array of these hashes or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell with the info you've provided -- it's clear you are NOT iterating over a hash as your question states, but rather something else (a MySQL::Dataset)?

If there's a DB behind it, the easiest thing to do would be to change the query that produced those records in the first place, probably with a `GROUP BY client` clause in your query.

If, instead, you actually have an array of hashes, then try this:

```
>> @var.map {|h| h[:client]}.uniq
=> ["CLIENT1", "CLIENT1 ", "CLIENT2 ", "CLIENT3 "]
```

or, since you have trailing spaces, maybe:

```
>> @var.map {|h| h[:client].strip}.uniq
=> ["CLIENT1", "CLIENT2", "CLIENT3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is apparently neither an array nor a hash, but a Sequel::Dataset. So I think what you want is `@var.distinct(:client)`.